# Wix Form Submission to Google Sheets

Tags: jquery, google-sheets-api, velo

I have read through hundreds of forum questions but cannot find a solution.

I want to send my Form Data (AfterSave) to Google Sheets

I created a Web App on Google Sheet which is something like this

```
function doGet(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}
        var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";

var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); 

function doPost(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

function handleResponse(e) {
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);  

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("1-L-rFuTM4oWbzcoLCfAoTGvvwC0iSiCdKtZRvl3RdRI"));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row = []; 

    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ 
        row.push(new Date());
      } else { 
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
      }
    }

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);

    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(e){

    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally { 
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}

function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1-L-rFuTM4oWbzcoLCfAoTGvvwC0iSiCdKtZRvl3RdRI');
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
```

Then I went ahead and created a Backend .JSW on my Wix Site which looks like this

```
//sendSheets.jsw

import {fetch} from 'wix-fetch';

export function sendToSheets(data) {    
    fetch("https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbykq05IP_ABzQfLa9ura_pISv-zwUHZdeGb2F9681ffyzubXi9I/exec", {
        method: 'post',
        body: data
    });
}
```

Finally on my Page Code it looks like this

```
import {sendToSheets} from 'backend/sendSheets.jsw'; 

$w.onReady(function () {
  $w("#dataset1").onAfterSave(sendToSheets);
});

export function sendFormData() {

    var data = {
        "input1":$w("#input1").value,
        "input2":$w("#input2").value,
        "dropdown1":$w("#dropdown1").value,
        "dropdown2":$w("#dropdown2").value
    };

    sendToSheets(data);

}
```

In the end the Script I created on Google Script Editor is showing that my Script ran a total of 7 times which is the exact amount of times I submitted a Form but nothing is posted on my sheets

I come from a Marketing Background and I only know a little bit of coding (I'm trying to learn) but I really cannot understand what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can now do this by adding a npm package for googleapi,
There is a great example template that demonstrates a form submission scenario.
The process involves two steps:
1) Configuring credentials and Auth2 tokens and saving them to a storage.
2) Calling google api on each form submission using the credentials.

at the end the form submission will look like this:

```

```
function insertRow(values, authClient, ssID) {
        var sheets = google.sheets('v4');
        const request = {
            spreadsheetId: ssID,  // The ID of the spreadsheet to update.
            valueInputOption: 'RAW',  // How the input data should be interpreted.
            insertDataOption: 'INSERT_ROWS',  // How the input data should be inserted.
            range: 'A1:A2', // The A1 notation of a range to search
                            // for a logical table of data. Values will be
                            // appended after the last row of the table.
            resource: {
                "values": [
                    values
                ]
            },
            auth: authClient,
        };
        try {
            return sheets.spreadsheets.values.append(request, function (err, response) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("error in append:" + err);
                    return;
                }
                return "ok";
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("error in append values" + err);
        `enter code here`}
    }
```

```

you can see the full example template here:
https://www.wix.com/code/home/forum/wix-tips-and-updates/example-google-sheets-npm